# Error While Adding Maven dependancy for org.apache.click

Tags: maven

I am adding maven dependance for org.apache.click. My code in pom.xml is below-

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.click</groupId>
        <artifactId>click</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

But when I run command mvn clean install It showing me error for org.apache.click.examples.page.BorderPage class

Exact Exception is :

src\main\java\AjaxConfig.java:[5,32] cannot find symbol
 symbol: class BorderPage
 public class AjaxConfig extends BorderPage{

Can someone sugest me what wrong I am doing....

Comment: done Subodh plese check now.

Comment: The class `org.apache.click.examples.page.BorderPage` is not defined in the dependency `org.apache.click:click`. It is also not available in any artifact that is hosted on maven central (if you use the advanced search you can search by class name - http://search.maven.org/#advancedsearch|gav). Why are you using this class? Are you following a tutorial or something similar? If you are following a tutorial, my guess is you would need to create this class yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it Actually BorderPage is an example in click2.3.0.jar So we need to create this by self and import that one in your class.

Thanks DB5 your suggestion is helpful to Me.